# Retag request: [region-locked] -> [region-lock]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

It would make more sense to have it as a noun than an adjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense. I merged [region-locked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/region-locked) into [region-lock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/region-lock) and created a synonym.